# Galaxy Nexus: very slow sensor readings

Tags: android, performance, delay, sensors

I have a really weird issue on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus - I try to read out some sensor values e.g. from the gyroscope. Very basic code, just a sensor listener putting the value in a list after doing simple integration over time.

When I run the code on a Nexus S for about 60 seconds, I can register about 60.000 sensor events (SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST) but if I ran it on the Galaxy Nexus, I only get about 6000 values in 60 seconds.

Is there a way to increase this? I really need more sensor data for what I'm doing and apart from the device, the only difference is the OS version: 4.0.2 on the Galaxy Nexus - 4.0.3 on the Nexus S.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Edit - the code:

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
LogSensorEventListener listener = new LogSensorEventListener(
       SensorLoggerActivity.this, Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
sm.registerListener(listener, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE),
       SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

LogSensorEventListener is also a very basic implementation of the SensorEventListenerInterface:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    final float dT = (event.timestamp - mTimestamp) / 1000000000.f;
    if (dT < 1) { // just a fix for the first step

        mRelZ += event.values[2] * dT;
        list.add(mRelZ);
        list2.add(event.timestamp);
    }
    mTimestamp = event.timestamp;
```

mRelZ is initially set to 0 and the two lists should keep track of time and measured value. If finished with my measurement (clicking a button) the values are written to file:

```
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            long time = list2.get(i);

            if (mStartTime < 0) {
                mStartTime = time;
                time = 0;
            } else {
                time = time - mStartTime;
            }

            float timef = time / 1000000000.0f;
            sb.append(timef);
            sb.append(";");
            sb.append(Math.toDegrees(list.get(i)));
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        mOutFileStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());

        mOutFileStream.flush();
        mOutFileStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: You need more dylithium crystals... and maybe to show us your code?

Comment: I added the code - but as said - nothing special with it and it runs perfectly and very fast on a Nexus S - but very slow on a Galaxy Nexus... btw. it does not matter if the power cable is on or off

Answer (score 0):

Android devices have no standards for how and when they report sensor changes. For instance, some devices won't report changes unless there ARE changes (e.g. the device is moving). Some devices will report tons of changes and others less changes even if you use the delay e.g. `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`.

Comment: Even if I rotate the device all the time, sometimes slow, sometimes fast, in all possible directions nothing changes - I only get about 6000 measurements in 60 seconds.
So it seems that I have to accept that the Galaxy Nexus will only report 100 measurements / second, whereas the Nexus S is able to show 1000?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It seems logical that it is hardware-limited, but also could be software-limited in some ROMs too.